# Turbolinks and javascript plugins in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I use javascript plugin, that converts couple of inputs to custom star rating picker. So, when turbolinks enabled and i use link_to to navigate to another page, javascript is not working (inputs displaying like standard ones).

**Script.js**

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+ ...
```

How can i solve this problem? Tried to attach some method on page load and etc., but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() { code here });
```